# Animation for the background makes the website "shake"

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a problem. I would like to create a kind of animation for falling hearts.
I have linked the code below how it should look like. However, this does not work as expected in `React.Js`. As soon as the hearts start to fall down the website starts to "shake". The scrollbar appears horizontally and vertically. In addition, the hearts are not behind the `container` as they should be.

How can I fix the error so that the hearts behave normally and the website does not start to shake as in the code example below and that they are behind the `container`?

Please note, that I added inside the `index.html` the this line

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4f3ce16e3e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import './style.css';

const Test= () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const body = document.querySelector("body");

    const createHeart = () => {
      const heart = document.createElement("div");
      heart.className = "fas fa-heart";
      heart.style.left = `${Math.random() * 100}vw`;
      heart.style.animationDuration = `${Math.random() * 3 + 2}s`;
      body.appendChild(heart);
    };

    const removeOldHearts = () => {
      const heartArr = document.querySelectorAll(".fa-heart");
      if (heartArr.length > 200) {
        heartArr[0].remove();
      }
    };

    const heartInterval = setInterval(createHeart, 100);
    const removeInterval = setInterval(removeOldHearts, 100);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(heartInterval);
      clearInterval(removeInterval);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div>
        <h1 className="header_text">Test</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


export default Test;
```

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 90vh;
    /*background-color: #ffffff;*/
    background: pink
}

#noButton {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 150px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

#yesButton {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 150px;
}

.header_text {
    font-family: 'Nunito';
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.buttons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.btn {
    background-color: #FFB6C1;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 12px;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.gif_container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) and (max-height: 568px) {
    body {
        height: 100vh;
    }

    .header_text {
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    img {
        height: 60vh;
    }

    .btn {
        padding: 10px 18px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 414px) and (max-height: 736px) {
    body {
        height: 90vh;
    }

    .header_text {
        font-size: 28px;
    }

    img {
        height: 60vh;
    }

    .btn {
        padding: 15px 25px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}

#container {
    min-width: 30%;
    min-height: 30%;
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 2px black;
    border-radius: 20px;
    z-index: 10;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-family: "Poppins",sans-serif;
}
.fa-heart {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    animation:  heartMove linear 1;
    top: -10vh;
    z-index: 0;
}

@keyframes heartMove {
    0%{
        transform: translateY(-10vh) ;
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateY(110vh) ;
    }
}
```

---

```js
const body = document.querySelector("body");

function createHeart() {
    const heart = document.createElement("div");
    heart.className = "fas fa-heart";
    heart.style.left = (Math.random() * 100)+"vw";
    heart.style.animationDuration = (Math.random()*3)+2+"s"
    body.appendChild(heart);
}
setInterval(createHeart,100);
setInterval(function name(params) {
    var heartArr = document.querySelectorAll(".fa-heart")
    if (heartArr.length > 200) {
       heartArr[0].remove()
    }
    //console.log(heartArr);
},100)
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap');

body{
    background: linear-gradient(45deg,pink,violet);
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#container {
    min-width: 30%;
    min-height: 30%;
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 2px black;
    border-radius: 20px;
    z-index: 10;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-family: "Poppins",sans-serif;
}
.fa-heart {
    color: rgb(256, 256, 256);
    font-size: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    animation:  heartMove linear 1;
    top: -10vh;
    z-index: 0;
}

@keyframes heartMove {
    0%{
        transform: translateY(-10vh) ;
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateY(110vh) ;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="container">
       Test
    </div>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4f3ce16e3e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem:

- The `hearts` are moving the bounds of your `body`, showing `scrollbars` cause it "overflows".

Solution 1, restricting your body:

- You can set your body to hide overflowing content: `overflow: hidden`.

Solution 2, you create a "restricted space" for hearts:

- You create a background `div` that will contains your hearts;
- And that `div` will be `absolute` or `fixed` in the background with the hidden overflow.

[Edit] (and snippet) to address the questions in comments

- You need to put your heart in a `<div/>` (here `id="hearts-container"`) that you put out of the scrolling flow by setting its position to `fixed`;
- Then send it to the back with `z-index: -1`;
- Remove any alteration of overflow from the `body`.

```js
const Test= () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const body = document.querySelector("#hearts-container");

    const createHeart = () => {
      const heart = document.createElement("div");
      heart.className = "fas fa-heart";
      heart.style.left = `${Math.random() * 100}vw`;
      heart.style.animationDuration = `${Math.random() * 3 + 2}s`;
      body.appendChild(heart);
    };

    const removeOldHearts = () => {
      const heartArr = document.querySelectorAll(".fa-heart");
      if (heartArr.length > 200) {
        heartArr[0].remove();
      }
    };

    const heartInterval = setInterval(createHeart, 100);
    const removeInterval = setInterval(removeOldHearts, 100);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(heartInterval);
      clearInterval(removeInterval);
    };
  }, []);

  return ([
    <div id="hearts-container"></div>,
    <div className="container">
      <div>
        <h1 className="header_text">Test</h1>
      </div>
    </div>,
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus elementum pretium leo. Nullam pellentesque aliquet nunc, vel porttitor erat tristique ac. Proin nec urna sagittis, sodales orci pretium, molestie nisl. Maecenas in orci vel orci mattis vehicula sit amet sed mi. Donec interdum metus sit amet fermentum cursus. Curabitur non urna sed nunc dignissim venenatis id vitae leo. Aliquam commodo et sapien vitae convallis. Praesent tempor fringilla ligula, vel sagittis ante pulvinar non. Mauris risus odio, blandit sed ligula vitae, tempor ornare nisi. Nulla finibus maximus ultricies. Suspendisse potenti. Ut lacus est, ornare vel mi eu, suscipit aliquam tellus. Nulla vehicula sed nisl eu efficitur.

Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris cursus suscipit venenatis. Mauris interdum luctus ultricies. Nullam aliquet, nibh id convallis suscipit, mi nunc mollis libero, a imperdiet ligula velit quis nunc. Suspendisse ut nunc vitae sem rhoncus varius at sed urna. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nunc euismod ligula sit amet tortor congue tristique dignissim eget purus.

Ut ipsum libero, molestie eu ultricies quis, tempus eget nunc. Fusce et lectus quam. Cras pharetra, felis non ullamcorper scelerisque, nulla nunc aliquet est, non aliquam magna tellus a justo. Cras faucibus eleifend lacus, in tincidunt ligula. Maecenas eget massa sed purus pellentesque consequat. Donec ut sapien at velit rutrum rutrum ut quis velit. Suspendisse eu ipsum augue. In tincidunt felis ac leo aliquet aliquet. Maecenas sit amet velit neque. Vestibulum sodales vel odio eu iaculis. Duis fringilla blandit efficitur. Curabitur tempor rutrum velit, in egestas mi tempor sed. Donec efficitur lacus sit amet erat interdum, nec vestibulum nisl congue. Nulla dictum commodo mollis. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam erat augue, vehicula sit amet dui vitae, volutpat tincidunt felis.

Nullam at est imperdiet, dictum lacus vel, sagittis libero. Ut placerat sapien finibus, dapibus lorem id, posuere tortor. Duis eu urna id nibh efficitur posuere id varius lorem. Aenean mi arcu, luctus at elementum at, dignissim vel sapien. Morbi lacinia velit eu dapibus commodo. Mauris malesuada, lorem sit amet mollis faucibus, purus mauris pellentesque arcu, eu tristique orci nunc id leo. Nunc vehicula ante lacus, ac consequat massa condimentum nec. Donec eu sollicitudin orci. Curabitur vel accumsan nisi.

Mauris eu dui magna. Fusce vitae ante tincidunt, sagittis ligula at, imperdiet sapien. Morbi fringilla a dolor eget euismod. Etiam consectetur finibus nunc, sed consequat ex hendrerit eu. Suspendisse ut mollis eros, vel eleifend est. Proin elit massa, fringilla ut est vitae, laoreet vestibulum leo. Sed convallis lacus nisi, eget iaculis ante luctus sit amet. Aenean ornare sit amet risus id sodales. Cras vitae dui varius, gravida nulla sit amet, volutpat justo. Nulla eleifend quis dolor at ullamcorper. Ut in venenatis arcu. Quisque id pulvinar turpis, id lacinia nunc. Quisque eros diam, suscipit non sodales feugiat, rutrum vitae quam. Nunc bibendum, lorem ut convallis sagittis, magna lectus cursus massa, elementum aliquet augue lacus id ante.
    </div>
  ]);
}


ReactDOM.render(<Test />,
document.getElementById("root"))
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap');

body{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.fa-heart {
    color: rgb(256, 256, 256);
    font-size: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    animation:  heartMove linear 1;
    top: -10vh;
    z-index: 0;
}

@keyframes heartMove {
    0%{
        transform: translateY(-10vh) ;
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateY(110vh) ;
    }
}

#hearts-container {
  position: fixed;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg,pink,violet);
  inset: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4f3ce16e3e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! `overflow: hidden` worked! And how about that the hearts are in front of the container and not in the back?

Comment: Depending of layout intrications but you can play with
[z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index), of your elements to set order, maybe `z-index: -1` would be fine.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, `z-index: -1` has not brought any change. 
And I have another question. Arrived, I have a button and this button makes more text appear. 
The following `overflow: hidden;` prevents the page from scrolling. How can I make the page scroll without the page starting to "shake"?

Comment: Added a snippet to answer your questions.